# Android "Hello World" Layout Problem on Galaxy Tab Screen

Tags: android, layout, netbeans, tabs

Hi guys :)
I'm trying to run a simple "Hello World" program with a button and a textview.
This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="text"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that it doesn't look good on the simulator with Samsung Galaxy Tab's resolution. The view doesn't take all available space as I wish but only a portion. Is "match_parent" correct in layout's width and height?

Comment: What *does* it look like? You look to have created a layout that fills the screen but your widgets are small and will not fill much space.

Comment: My program is for Samsung Galaxy Tab, it should be 1280x1024. But actually the main view is smaller and centered in the emulator's screen. The layout doesn't fill the screen, this is the problem :(

Comment: SOLVED! :D just added this string in the manifest.xml after </application>: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

Comment: Please add the answer as a response to your question and mark it as the accepted answer. Stackoverflow doesn't operate the same as a forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLUTION: add `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />` in the manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be `fill_parent`

Comment: match_parent is a synonym for fill_parent included in 2.x.

Comment: From the Dev Guide:
fill_parent (renamed match_parent in API Level 8) tells your view to become as big as its parent view group will allow

Answer (score 0):

```
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
```

try this... it may work.

Comment: fill_parent is the same as match_parent. From the Dev Guide: fill_parent (renamed match_parent in API Level 8) tells your view to become as big as its parent view group will allow